# OrderBy not working for multiple properties in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this table. I want to sort by the date(day,month). I am able to sort by the day when i use the below code but i am not being able to sort for both day and month by `orderBy:['day','month']`.So it shows 6/9/2015 before 7/8/2015 . Can give me clues what is wrong?

```
<h1>Reservations</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="heading in data1.headings">{{heading}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations|orderBy:'day'" ng-show="reservation.is_approved">
            <td>{{reservation.id}}</td>
            <td>{{reservation.user.fb_id}}</td>
            <td>{{reservation.user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{reservation.user.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{reservation.user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{reservation.day}}/{{reservation.month}}/{{reservation.year}}</td>           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to sort by month first? Then it should be: `orderBy: ['month', 'day']`

Comment: hahaha. I don't know why i didn't think it at the first place. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your date to Javascript Date object and after that the proper sorting can be apllied.

So in your controller do: *(update to your needs)*

```
reservations[i].date = new Date(year, month, day);
```

You can use [many formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to create Javascript date object.

After that, you should be able to sort by the date correctly.

```
<tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations|orderBy:'date'" ng-show="reservation.is_approved">
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because orderBy dont know that inject dates. It just sort by numbers. You should add to your app filter to parse your data to correct Date and sort your array:

```
app.filter('filterByDate', function filterByDate() {
  return function(array, descending) {
    var order = descending ? 1 : -1;

    array.sort(function(a, b) {
      return (new Date(b.year, b.month, b.day) - new Date(a.year, a.month, a.day)) * order;
    });

    return array;
  };
});
```

and use this like that:

```
<tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations|filterByDate" ng-show="reservation.is_approved">
    <td>{{reservation.id}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.fb_id}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.day}}/{{reservation.month}}/{{reservation.year}}</td>           
</tr>
```

or if you want to sort date by descending add parameter "true" to filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations|filterByDate:true" ng-show="reservation.is_approved">
    <td>{{reservation.id}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.fb_id}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{reservation.day}}/{{reservation.month}}/{{reservation.year}}</td>           
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

by default orderBy use ascending sort, u can use ['day','-month'] get descending order by month
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy